# how to validate Date of birth with three textbox of date month year by jquery validator

Tags: javascript, jquery-validate

I need to validate date of birth by using jquery validator with three separate textbox for day month and year.

How to do this please help.

HTML code

```
<input type="text" maxlength="2" placeholder="DD" class="dob-day  fillone" name="dob-day" id="dob-day" data-fieldgroup="dob" data-fillone-field="true" />
<input type="text" maxlength="2" placeholder="MM" id="dob-month" class="dob-month fillone" data-fieldgroup="dob" data-fillone-field="true">
<input type="text" maxlength="4" placeholder="YYYY" class="dob-year fillone" id="dob-year" data-fieldgroup="dob" data-fillone-field="true">
```

I am using data-group for grouping the textbox

Answer (score 3):

You should create a custom validation method for this, along with using the  `groups` option that validate provides:

```
/* Custom validation method to validate a date based on several fields: */
$.validator.addMethod("datemultiple", function(value, element, params) {
    var daySelector = params[0],
        monthSelector = params[1],
        yearSelector = params[2],
        day = parseInt($(daySelector).val(), 10),
        month = parseInt($(monthSelector).val(), 10),
        year = parseInt($(yearSelector).val(), 10),
        dateEntered = new Date(year, month - 1, day);

    return this.optional(element) || !isNaN(dateEntered.valueOf());

}, "Please enter a valid date");

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myform").validate({
        groups: {
            /* Only display one validation message for day, month, and year: */
            dateOfBirth: "dob-day dob-month dob-year"
        },
        rules: {
            'dob-day': {
                required: true,
                datemultiple: ["#dob-day", "#dob-month", "#dob-year"]
            },
            'dob-month': {
                required: true
            }
        },
        /* Place error messages after the "year" field */
        errorPlacement: function ($error, $element) {
            if ($element.data("fieldgroup") === "dob") {
                $error.insertAfter("#dob-year");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/xHC86/

Comment: what if you would want to "wait" for all 3 inputs to be filled and then validate? Of course you could check if they all are filled, then validate. But that will cause problems when you actually submit - by pressing on the submit button.

Comment: in your example, if I fill one field, and then move to the second - the error message is displayed. What if I want to wait for the user to fill in ALL three elements and THEN validate? It's like cross field validation.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a Javascript module that handles whether or not the data is valid, you can check out a full working example in the JSFiddle link.

http://jsfiddle.net/dceast/vmHjN/

Here is the module that does the validation:

```
var compareDate, checkDates = false;
var validateObject = {
    init: function(year, month, day) {
        return this.compareDate.init(year, month, day);
    },
    compareDate: {
        init: function(year, month, day) {
            var isValid = false;
            // Compensate for zero based index, if month was not
            // subtracted from one 0 === Jan, 1 === Feb, 2 === Mar
            month -= 1;

            // Create a new date object with the selected
            // year, month, and day values and retrieve the
            // milliseconds from it.
            var mSeconds = (new Date(year, month, day)).getTime();
            var objDate = new Date();

            // Set the time of the object to the milliseconds 
            // retrieved from the original date. This will
            // convert it to a valid date.
            objDate.setTime(mSeconds);

            // Compare if the date has changed, if it has then
            // the date is not valid 
            if (objDate.getFullYear() === year &&
                objDate.getMonth() === month &&
                objDate.getDate() === day) 
            {
                isValid = true;
            }
            return isValid;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: its a great code but it will be great if you can please change this in jquery validator formate

Answer (score 0):

sorry, i'm cannot speak english

you can check date < 30 or 31 respectively month
month < 12
year ...

i think it's easy when you used three textbox :(
just js

Answer (score 0):

```
var compareDate, checkDates = false;
var validateObject = {
    init: function(year, month, day) {
        return this.compareDate.init(year, month, day);
    },
    compareDate: {
        init: function(year, month, day) {
            var isValid = false;
            // Compensate for zero based index, if month was not
            // subtracted from one 0 === Jan, 1 === Feb, 2 === Mar
            month -= 1;

            // Create a new date object with the selected
            // year, month, and day values and retrieve the
            // milliseconds from it.
            var mSeconds = (new Date(year, month, day)).getTime();
            var objDate = new Date();

            // Set the time of the object to the milliseconds
            // retrieved from the original date. This will
            // convert it to a valid date.
            objDate.setTime(mSeconds);

            // Compare if the date has changed, if it has then
            // the date is not valid
            if (objDate.getFullYear() === year&&
                objDate.getMonth() === month &&
                objDate.getDate() === day)
            {                
                if(objDate <= new Date())
                {
                    isValid = true;
                }                   
            }
            return isValid;
        }
    }
};

$(function() {
    var validateButton = $('#btValidate');

    validateButton.click(function(e) {
        var month = parseInt(document.getElementById('month').value, 0),
            day = parseInt(document.getElementById('day').value, 0),
            year = parseInt(document.getElementById('year').value, 0),
            alertBox = $('#alert'),
            isValid = false;

        isValid = validateObject.init(year, month, day);
        var color, message;

        if (isValid === true)
        {
            color = "#008000";
            message = "Your date is valid!";
        }
        else if (isValid === false)
        {
            color = "#F00";
            message = "Your date is not valid!";
        }
        alertBox.css('background', "" + color)
            .html("<p>"+ message +"</p>")
            .stop()
            .animate({
                width: "200px",
                paddingLeft: "75px"
            }, 1750, "easeOutBounce", function() {
                $(this).animate({
                    width: "0px",
                    paddingLeft: "0px"
                }, 1000, "easeInBounce");
        });
    });
});
```

Working code here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/vmHjN/140/

Comment: Please paste code directly into your answer, and also provide some explanation as to how the code helps the OP.